# In C++, is there a way to programmatically open a webpage in Chrome and access its content?

Tags: c++, google-chrome

My problem is that I cannot access the page directly. However I can access it in Chrome and see its code. So I wonder if there is a way to access it indirectly through loading it in Chrome first.

EDIT : I was not clear enough. The webpage I want to load, grants access only to browsers. I tried cUrl and setting Google Chrome as the agent, but it didn't work.

Comment: why dont you look for a web scraping library? You would be going way out of your way to open chrome first.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "access see its code"? Typically, if you want to "fetch" the content of a web-page, `curl` or `wget` would be my approach, rather than big, heavy Chrome.

Comment: ...or even use a `libcurl`/`curlpp` so no process spawning is needed.

Comment: What a strange way to retrieve web content!

Comment: How are you trying to access the page "directly"? With Windows API stuff like WinINet? And what goes wrong when you try?

Comment: @Mr Lister : Using cUrl. I received a blank page. After researching the matter, I found that the webpage is only available to web browsers  (site owner is worried of massive crawling)

Comment: Have a look at the headers chrome is sending to the page. Most likely you will be able to mimic them from curl and get the content.

Comment: I think, you only need to mimic `User-Agent` and would be enough. Also, there is not just Chrome, but a great deal of other browsers...

Comment: If you mimic the "User-Agent" and "Referer" field correctly, the server will not be able to tell that you are using a customized program instead of a browser. Sometime you may also have to build up the list of cookies that the server is expecting, from a series of http calls consecutively.

Comment: If they only allow access to browsers, and you're circumventing that restriction; you're at best violating their TOS.  Distributing a product that by default mimics a commercial browser is also a big _no_ from a legal standpoint.  Contact the site administrators and ask them to let your custom user agent access it, or give you a proper RPC URL.

Answer (score 0):

No, modern web browsers don't allow the sort of client-side automation you're looking for because of the obvious security hole if malicious software could access the web with the user's credentials.

You could look into your platform's UI automation if you don't mind actually bringing the page up in front of the user.  Effectively you'd navigate to each URL and either view-source and copy to clipboard or Save As... to a temporary file.

Comment: If it was for only one page, it might work. But fetching 10 pages and copying the code manually won't work.

Answer (score 0):

This will open the URL in the default web browser:

```
void OpenWebsite (char * cpURL)
{
    ShellExecute (NULL, "open", cpURL, NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL); 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Normal browsers does not allow that for security reason. 
But there are tools aimed for automated testing like [selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) which can do it